# iOS Distribution Certificate expiration management

Tags: ios

We have distributed more than 50 iOS applications using a iOS Distribution Certificate (in-house, internal use apps).The apps are in house apps and distributed through our MDM solution. The iOS Distribution Certificate is going to be expire soon. When we checked the expiry of iOS Distribution Certificate in apple documentation, we got following information.

**iOS Distribution Certificate (in-house, internal use apps)
Users will no longer be able to run apps that have been signed with this certificate. You must distribute a new version of your app that is signed with a new certificate**

As the apps are used in many stores real time, if we are sign the app with new certificate and then we need to re distribute it and  will affect all the internal network. We are thinking to move the update on a nightly time.  Can you suggest any solution other than this?

Answer (score 2):

You should talk to your MDM vendor regarding deployment strategy. The topics on Stackoverflow are intended to be more technical in nature. Your vendor will have a lot more experience than you on this and should be able to provide best practices to you. There are many factors involved: network capacity, devices online/offline, etc.